# How to set a maximum value of string that can be shown in a matrix?

Tags: c#, matrix

I'm trying to make a matrix that will show the string s only if it it displays a number less than 10. It would probably be easier doing this with an integer instead of the string but it doesn't show the same 8x8(or any other combination) the same because the "string.Empty" seems to be being the key(if someone could explain that part too, it would help me).

I also want to know how to display lets say letter "a" in the whole matrix, so that if the matrix is 3x3 I see 3 "a" in 3 rows.

Code here shows me matrix which lets s go over 10 which makes it not looking like a square.

[image: Matrix looks like this now]

```
string s = "";            
int[,] matrix = new int[8, 8];

for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
{
     for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
     {                       
          s += matrix[i, j] = i + j;
     }
     Console.WriteLine(s);
     s = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: this will fix. you don't have to omit numbers bigger than 10 .`s += (matrix[i, j] = i + j) + "\t";`

Comment: Sometimes, i+j is greater than 10 what gives strings longer than 8 digits. you may systematically use 2 digits per value, by left padding to 2 characters.

Comment: Alternatively you could do `s += (matrix[i, j] = i + j).ToString().PadLeft(3);` for right aligned numbers.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to do this with a int instead of string? Or how to write "a" in each matrix field? Thanks

Comment: A string.char `a` will not fit in an `int`. or did you mean the Hex value `a`

Comment: Try: `s += (matrix[i, j] = i + j).ToString("X");` for displaying hex values.;